Why is the set of decomposable tensors closed under any norm-induced topology?
Given a finite-dimensional tensor product $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$, an element of it is said to be decomposable if it can be written in the form $v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k$ where $v_i \in V_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, k$. I read online that the set of these decomposable tensors are closed under any norm-induced topology. However, it did not include a proof. Could someone prove why this is true? And why is this not true for infinite dimensional tensor products?

On finite-dimensional spaces, all norms are equivalent, so we might as well pretend $V_i$ are all inner product spaces and the norm on $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$ is induced by the usual inner product on tensor products. Assume $(v_1^i \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k^i)_i$ is a sequence of decomposable tensors which converges to some $v$. Since $\sup_i \|v_1^i\| \cdots \|v_k^i\| = \sup_i \|v_1^i \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k^i\| < \infty$, we may normalize the norms s.t. $\sup_i \|v_j^i\| < \infty$ for all $1 \leq j \leq k$. Then by compactness, we may take a subsequence and assume $\lim_{i \to \infty} v_j^i = v_j$ for some $v_j \in V_j$, for all $1 \leq j \leq k$. But then a direct calculation shows that $v_1^i \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k^i \to v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k$, so $v = v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k$ is a decomposable tensor. (Technically, for this proof, any norms on $V_j$ and any tensor norm on the tensor product would do just as well. I’m simply using inner product norms to make this somewhat more explicit.)

As for the infinite-dimensional case, I assume you meant the case where some of $V_j$ is infinite-dimensional? In that case you can always impose a norm on the tensor product s.t. the decomposable tensors are not closed. We can assume $V_j$ are all normed, and we may choose a tensor norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$. Now, say, assume WLOG that $V_1$ is infinite-dimensional. Then we may pick a non-closed subspace $W \subset V_1$. Fix a sequence $w_n \in W$ which converges to some $w \in V_1 \setminus W$. Fix any $v_j \in V_j \setminus \{0\}$ for $j \geq 2$. Fix a indecomposable $v \in (V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k) \setminus (W \otimes V_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k)$. Then we may choose a linear isomorphism $f: V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k \to V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$ s.t. $f|_{W \otimes V_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k} = \text{Id}_{W \otimes V_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k}$ and $f(v) = w \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k$. Now, $\|x\|’ = \|f(x)\|$ is a new norm on $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$, but under $\|\cdot\|’$ we have the decomposable tensors $w_n \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k$ converges to the indecomposable $v$.

Oh, that's nice. I believe it furthermore ought to be true that the decomposable tensors are Zariski-closed and cut out by polynomials generalizing the quadratic polynomials defining the Segre embedding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding); do you know a nice way to prove this other than by induction on $k$?

@QiaochuYuan I agree it does seem like it should be true. But I wouldn’t know how to prove it. Algebraic geometry is not really my strong suit.

@QiaochuYuan Would you mind showing how the set o decomposable tensors are Zariski-closed? And is this also only for finite dimensional Hilbert spaces?

@jujumumu: unfortunately I don't know a nice proof of this (other than inducting based on the Segre embedding). I also don't know what happens in infinite dimensions.

@QiaochuYuan Where could I find the induction based proof of this?
